# Example of smooth function with max-min $\ne$ min-max

Tags: optimization, maxima-minima

I'm some difficulty developing intuition for saddle-points. I would like to see an example of a smooth function $f:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ for which

$$\min_x\max_yf(x,y) > \max_y\min_xf(x,y)$$

A trivial example is $f(x,y) = \sin(x+y)$ (https://math.stackexchange.com/a/186746/10063). However in this case the min-max and max-min are not isolated points so first-order and second-order locality conditions do not characterize the saddle-point completely.

So I would like to see an example where the min-max and max-min are different **isolated** points, contained inside the domain (not on the boundary), so that first and second-order optimality conditions are meaningful.

Comment: Just take the Lagrangian of an SDP for which strong duality does not hold. There are plenty of examples, e.g., (12.12) at https://www.cs.cmu.edu/afs/cs.cmu.edu/academic/class/15859-f11/www/notes/lecture12.pdf

Comment: @LinAlg You mean a quadratic problem? In that case critical points are not isolated

Comment: I mean, I understand your point, but I'm just trying to educate my intuition here. Just need a simple 2D example that I can plot. I want to see how the vector field of the gradient of $f$ looks around the two kinds of points.

Comment: How about $f(x,y) = (x+y)^2$ on $[0,1] \times [-0.5,1]$? The minmax is at $(x,y) = (0,1)$ while the maxmin is at $(1,0)$.

Comment: @LinAlg Sorry if I wasn't clear. I am interested in seeing how the first and second order conditions are reflected in the example. I can't do that if the optimal points are on boundary.

Comment: Have a look at what happens if you multiply your ([my](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/186746/1508)) example by $1/(x^2+y^2+1)$. I haven't analysed it, but my intuition says it should do what you want.